# relacionamento distante com laravel

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Tenho essa estrutura de tabela e gostaria de saber se quem postou a *thread* ou a *reply* é *member* ou *moderator*, mas não consegui estruturar um relacionamento que funciona, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
forum
      id - integer
      name - string

users
     id - integer
     name - string

threads
     id - integer
     user_id - integer
     communitie_id - integer
     title - string
     body - text

 replies 
     id - integer     
     thread_id - integer    
     author_id - integer    
     title - string    
     body - text

 forum_user
     forum_id - integer
     user_id - integer 
     type - moderator/member/owner
```

Comment: Qual o relacionamento entre as entidades ? Tens que começar por ai.

Comment: community* que banco de dados você usa?

Comment: Eu uso mysql, mas to usando o eloquent

Comment: O campo `communitie_id` na tabela `threads` aponta para um item na tabela `forum`, é isso?

Comment: @Cahe sim, eu até editei o código.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez você possa utilizar a biblioteca `Triple Pivot`.

Veja aqui o link e alguns exemplos:

https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot

Comment: Por favor, poderia incluir um exemplo na resposta para não ficar dependente somente do link?

Comment: na hora do meu almoço faço isso, @utluiz